# Can the proof of the central limit theorem be expressed as the limit of a convolution with an operator

Tags: mean, central-limit-theorem, fourier-transform, integral

The central limit theorem, as I understand it (engineer, non-statistician), says that the distribution comprised of means of some other reasonably behaved distributions converges to a normal distribution in the limit as sample size goes to infinity.

Convolution (1d) between scalar values is shown [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Convolution.html).

The mean can be considered an expectation operator.  Can the central limit theorem be expressed as 
N(mu,sig) = conv(scalar values, operator)

I am thinking to explore frequency domain deconvolution to learn about the nature of the distribution upon which the mean is being operated, but need help to determine if it can be expressed in these terms, and then to express it in a way that is useful.

If so please give complete details.

Comment: You're almost there: the mean is not just a convolution; it has to be *standardized* in order for convergence to occur. "Complete details" appear in any rigorous statistics textbook; Kendall & Stuart is a standard reference.

Comment: @whuber: this one? http://amzn.com/0470669543

Comment: Yes: see volume 1.